# Why do some institutions close IRA accounts when the account holder moves to another country or spends most of their time outside of the US?

Tags: united-states, ira, international, moving

I read on the Merrill Edge's traditional IRA application page:

> Note: If your residence changes (e.g., you move to another country or spend most of your time outside of the United States), Merrill Edge will not be able to maintain your account. You will be required to close the account.

[image]

Why do some institutions close IRA accounts when the account holder  moves to another country or spends most of their time outside of the United States?

Comment: Do you have evidence that some institutions _don't_ do this? (I'm in the UK and have no idea; hence the question). It _might_ be a regulatory thing that all institutions must comply with. If not, and they've _chosen_ to impose this condition, then it's presumably to save them the (perceived) hassle of communicating overseas.

Comment: @TripeHound I've read other questions on this SE that said one can have an IRA while living outside the US.

Comment: @TripeHound Wells Fargo are quite happy to keep my IRA open so long as I file a W8-BEN every three years.

Comment: As to why Merrill Edge doesn't allow this, I can only assume that they have decided that the additional costs in postage, compliance paperwork, exposure to fraud and so on are more than the profits they make from these accounts.

Comment: @TripeHound, I take it back. Wells Fargo have just asked me to close my IRA, 12 years after I left the USA.

Comment: @RupertMorrish thanks for the update, on what ground did Wells Fargo close your IRA account? If it's because you live abroad: How did they know you left the US? Did your contract mentioned that if you leave the USA you account will be closed?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt They state it's because I'm normally resident overseas. They've always been aware of my location - this is a new policy on their part, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt See my question on the topic: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/89425/bank-has-asked-me-to-close-my-ira?noredirect=1#comment155902_89425

Comment: @RupertMorrish thanks! Do you have to pay some closing fee?

Comment: @TripeHound "save them the (perceived) hassle of communicating overseas." -> I would expect this hassle to be negligible compared to the money they get from all the account management fees. Which hassle do you have in mind? Many of them use emails nowadays.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Personally, I fully agree the actual cost/hassle probably is negligible; however, bureaucracy being what it is, I can also see how a company might not want to bother... Postal costs: Most financial institutions (at least in the UK) won't send detailed info by email: traditionally this was done by post (although increasingly they may post it to an online portal). Legal issues: if anything ever has to be "formally served", there _may_ be complications if the recipient is overseas. None of these is a real excuse, but I can see how a company might want to avoid "complications".

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4A0nvCYm0gw) points to foreign and
domestic laws regarding tax compliance and "Know Your Client" rules as having
pushed financial institutions into a state of "hypercompliance" from which they
would rather escape (by closing non-resident accounts).